# Field 'id' expected a number - Uploading ForeignKey to django-import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to import data from an csv file into a django db using django-import-export. My problem is trying to upload data with a ForeignKey as an object. I have migrated, followed docs, and still no solution. You can see my error below in the django admin:

[image]

Here is my csv data with a blank 'Id' column:

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class States(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=96, blank=False, unique=True)
    abbrv = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = 'State'
        verbose_name_plural = 'States'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, help_text="Enter your last name.")
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, help_text="Enter your first name or first initial.")
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Enter your street address.")
    city = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Enter your city.")
    state = models.ForeignKey('States', to_field='name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField(
        max_length=255, blank=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    # META CLASS
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Persons'
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    # TO STRING METHOD
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person, States

from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from import_export import fields, resources

class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    state = fields.Field(
    column_name='state',
    attribute='state',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(States, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'state')
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' )
    resources_class = PersonResource



admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register(States)
```

Comment: @WPWIV.
Help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015477/how-to-pass-a-filter-from-a-dropdown-into-django-import-export-view

Answer (score 1):

This error is occur because your id did not received an id or `int` value it received a `str` type of value `Wyoming` try to pass `int` value in id

### Update

just update your `PersonResource` **Meta** class like this

```
class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    state = fields.Field(
    column_name='state',
    attribute='state',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(States, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        import_id_fields = ['id']
```

> The default field for object identification is id, you can optionally
> set which fields are used as the id when importing

check official [doc.](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I added a number to each id column and still the same error.

Comment: you got 8 columns in your Person table but you are receiving only 6 values only website and id fields are getting remaining data which is form of `str` from that's why it is giving error i think

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify both in your question here, as well as to Django how you want the id field treated.

Do you want it propagated with the Django id or pk (sometimes the same sometimes not)?  Then you would have id=self.id or id=self.pk somewhere in your view for the datatable.

Do you want your database to create a unique key?

You would need to add some functionality someplace to tell Django how to fill in that field.
Also, if you want it to create an id different from the Django id or pk then you would need to add the field to your model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/

Or, perhaps after Validation of the form, when you create the object.  Add something to the effect of id=[database function to create unique id].

Another solution might be a templateTag or templateFilter to create a value on the form side if you want to create the id based on info contained in the form.  Like combining last 4 of name with time of submission.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Having just re-read your question, also, I'm not sure but you might be asking if the database can support an embedded reference to another object. Is ID a reference to another model's key?  That's a whole different question.  And it is database specific.

Last Suggestion:  Perhaps a re-read of:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships