# How to use the form values inside form_valid function in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I would like to know how to use the inputted values into a form in the form_valid function in my view. First of all, here is the view:

```
class OrganisorStudentUpdateView(OrganisorAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    # some code
    form_class = OrganisorStudentUpdateModelForm
    # some code

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        # some variables from form

        print(form.instance.weekday.all())

        # some extra mathematical code using the values of form.instance.weekday.all()
        # update some of the other form fields

        print(form.instance.weekday.all())
        return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

`weekday` in `form.instance.weekday.all()` is a many to many field in the form that is linked to another model. The problem is that I need to click the update button twice in order to do the mathematical code with the values from `weekday`. Here is a simple example. My current values for the `weekday` form field is the "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday" checkboxes checked. When I update the form without changing anything, the following is printed:

```
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Monday>, <Weekday: Wednesday>, <Weekday: Friday>]>
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Monday>, <Weekday: Wednesday>, <Weekday: Friday>]>
```

Then, I will change my values for `weekday` to "Tuesday" and "Thursday". I updated. I got this:

```
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Monday>, <Weekday: Wednesday>, <Weekday: Friday>]>
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Monday>, <Weekday: Wednesday>, <Weekday: Friday>]>
```

This is not what I want, as you can see. I want Tuesday and Thursday to show up. However, this only happens if I update this form one more time:

```
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Tuesday>, <Weekday: Thursday>]>
<QuerySet [<Weekday: Tuesday>, <Weekday: Thursday>]>
```

This also means that all of my mathematical codes work(and thus update other parts of the form field) when I click the update button twice.

I hope you guys could help me make "Tuesday" and "Thursday"(the newly changed values) appear in my form_valid function, so that I don't have to update two times. Thanks, and let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Try `self.cleaned_data`, is it what you want?

Comment: Can you show me exactly how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access those values via `form.cleaned_data` method:

```
def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    # some variables from form

    print(form.cleaned_data)

    # some extra mathematical code using the values of form.instance.weekday.all()
    # update some of the other form fields

    print(form.instance.weekday.all())
    return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

But it would be best if you put those code inside form's code. For example:

```
class OrganisorStudentUpdateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def clean_weekday(self):  # assuming you have a field weekday
      # otherwise use 'clean()' method.
      weekday = self.cleaned_data.get('weekday')
      # do some calculation
      return weekday
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: Help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015477/how-to-pass-a-filter-from-a-dropdown-into-django-import-export-view/67019083#67019083 @ruddra